# Find the right technical word for a composition of names

Tags: grammar

I have the following text from which I extracted the pair of words **Abbott Laboratories**

> A unit of pharmaceutical giant **Abbott Laboratories** agreed to pay 600
> million dollars to settle criminal and civil charges of defrauding
> government health care agencies.

---

## Question

What is the grammatical identification of Laboratories or what is the right technical word.
What is the relation between **Abbott** and **Laboratories**. **Laboratories** is telling us that **Abbott** is the name of a laboraty which is an **organization** and not a **person**.

Comment: It's just a name. They could have named it "Potato Skunkworks", but that probably wouldn't have conveyed the image they wanted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking about the "internal syntax" of a *proper noun*. There is no such thing (or certainly, *needn't be* any such thing).

Comment: @FumbleFingers "There is no such thing (or certainly, needn't be any such thing)." -- indeed there is.

Answer (score 5):

**Abbott Laboratories** is the name of the company. There might be a person named Abbott, or a place named Abbott, or a technical process named Abbott... and whoever set up this company (which presumably does most of its work in laboratories) chose to name their company **Abbott Laboratories**.

Hence **Abbott Laboratories** is a [proper noun](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/proper+noun).

The word, *laboratories* itself is a noun.

Comment: I wonder what the up votes are for! Is the question understood, in the first place?

Comment: @Kris - I thought I understood it. And the upvoters presumably agree with my interpretation. I believe the OP didn't realise that "Laboratories" was part of the company name. Hence my answer: it is part of a proper noun.

Comment: "I believe the OP didn't realise" or rather, seriously, the OP had never meant what is stated this answer, maybe?